# NodeJs - Refactored Authenticate middleware callback error

Tags: node.js

***I am experiencing a refactoring issue and I cannot see how to correct the matter:***

**1. This section of code, NOT REFACTORED, works properly:**

```
'use strict';
  // will use svcs when refactoring
  var svcs = require('../../../services/ensure-authenticated.server.service'), 
  config = require('../../../config/config.server.config.js'),
  ctrl = require('../../../controllers/index.server.controller'),
  express = require('express'),
  router = express.Router();

  // will remove when refactoring
  var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
  var moment = require('moment');

 // to be refactored
 function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.headers.authorization) {
        return res.status(401).send({message: 'Please make sure your request has an Authorization header'});
    }
    var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    var payload = jwt.decode(token, config.token_secret);
    if (payload.exp <= moment().unix()) {
        return res.status(401).send({message: 'Token has expired'});
    }
    req.user = payload.sub;
    next();}


module.exports = function(app){
     router.route('/me')
      // middleware will change when refactored
      .get(ensureAuthenticated, ctrl.userCtrl.getMe)
      .put(ensureAuthenticated, ctrl.userCtrl.putMe);

  app.use('/api', router);
 }
```

---

**2a. But if I refactor ensure authenticate:**

```
'use strict';

var config = require('../config/config.server.config.js');
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
var moment = require('moment');

var self = {
  ensureAuthenticated: function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.headers.authorization) {
        return res.status(401).send({message: 'Please make sure your request has an Authorization header'});
    }
    var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    var payload = jwt.decode(token, config.TOKEN_SECRET);
    if (payload.exp <= moment().unix()) {
        return res.status(401).send({message: 'Token has expired'});
    }
    req.user = payload.sub;
    next();
  }
}
 module.exports = self;
```

**2b. With my route now looking like this:**

```
'use strict';
var svcs = require('../../../services/ensure-authenticated.server.service.js'),
ctrl = require('../../../controllers/index.server.controller.js'),
express = require('express'),
router = express.Router();


module.exports = function(app, config){
router.route('/me')
    .get(svcs, ctrl.userCtrl.getMe)
    .put(svcs, ctrl.userCtrl.putMe);
app.use('/api', router);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
 Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Object]
```

The code has not changed in the least, it has only be refactored and I cannot see why this is happening.

Does anyone see why this is happening and how to correct?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Silly mistake on my part:**

```
   .get(svcs.ensureAuthenticated, ctrl.userCtrl.getMe)
   .put(svcs.ensureAuthenticated, ctrl.userCtrl.putMe);
```